# How to make git download a new folder after editing sparse-checkout?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I have a git repo where I only want to download certain subfolders.  My config looks like this:

```
#.git/config

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    sparsecheckout = true
[remote "dreamhost"]
  url = <repo url>
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dreamhost/*
[push]
  default = tracking
```

In `.git/info/sparse-checkout` i had this:

```
themes/theme1
themes/theme8
```

which are the folders within the `themes` subfolder that I want to get.  (I don't need the others, which are many).

If i do a git/pull I can see git fetching lots of stuff, including the `themes` subfolders which I don't want, which is fine.  I know that sparse-checkout still pulls down the objects.

I now want to have a copy of `themes/theme15`, to make some changes.  So, I edited `.git/info/sparse-checkout` thus:

```
themes/theme1
themes/theme8
themes/theme15
```

and then did a `git pull dreamhost master`, thinking that git would add the theme15 folder under `themes`.  But, nothing happens - it just says

```
From <repo url>
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

and the folder's not there.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Is there an extra step after editing `.git/info/sparse-checkout`?

thanks, Max

EDIT:  this is in `git version 2.8.1` btw

Answer (score 18):

The step I needed to perform to make my folder appear after adding it to my sparse-checkout file was:

```
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
git sparse-checkout reapply
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30849755)

Comment: This also work to undo `git sparse-checkout add`:  remove the files and directories from the worktree then remove appropriate lines from `.git/info/sparse-checkout` and finally run `git sparse-checkout reapply` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77665917/4669135)).

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out, I'll answer it in case anyone else has the same problem.

After making the change I needed to do

```
git checkout themes/theme15
```

then the folder appears.  Perhaps obvious in hindsight....(perhaps not).

Answer (score 0):

Since git 2.25 there's a new command, `git sparse-checkout`, intended to help with these flows (so you generally wouldn't edit the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file, or change the `core.sparsecheckout` setting manually anymore).

It's still experimental as of git 2.27, so might change in exact functionality & syntax.

Doc: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout